# Yii2 conditional validation on radio box

Tags: validation, yii, yii2, conditional-statements

I'm trying to use conditional validation on a attribute `account_no`. It should be validate only when I select the value 'old' in the attribute `account_version`. But it is not working. The error I'm getting is validation is required for `new`also. Should I use javascript instead to validate

My code in model

```
return [
        ['account_no', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
            return $model->account_version == 'Old';
        }], 
      ]
```

My code in form

```
<?php if ($model->isNewRecord) {?> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="">Account Version</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <?php  echo $form->field($model, 'account_version')->radioList(['New'=>'New','Old'=>'Old'])->label(false); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="action_block" class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="">Account No:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'account_no')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
return [


        ['account_no', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
            return $model->account_no == 'Old';
        }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
            return $('#account_no').val() == 'Old';
        }"]
      ]


?>
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html [reference links]

Comment: I add that also but still not functioning as yii2 validation. It seems there is an issue with conditional validation of yii2 on radio box. [Refer this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7496)

Comment: @gojiraki. Issue got solved in Yii 2.0.7 and latest version don't have any problem with conditional validation. Working fine with Ajax.

Comment: @InsaneSkull I think it works fine with text input but with radio box I'm still having trouble. Can you show me how its done?

Comment: @gojiraki. Using Ajax validation also works with radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

```
[['account_no'], 'required', 'when' => function ($model) { return $model->account_version == 'Old'; }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) { return $('#modelName[account_version]').val() == 'Old'; }"],
```

**Form**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'account-form', 'enableAjaxValidation' => true]); ?>
```

**Controller**

```
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
}
```